# Cloud Run mapping services by URL path (using custom domain and wildcards)

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, routes, google-cloud-run

I've been trying to migrate my solution from Google Cloud App Engine to Google Cloud Run and have been struggling a lot.

I have 3 services in app engine for each staging environment, let's call them `api`, `front1`, `front2`. `front1` has custom domain name assigned `www.example.com`, as well as staging subdomain `www.dev.example.com`. Using `dispatch.yaml` rules I route requests to appropriate services, for example: requests containing `api/*` are routed to `api` service, default path routes to `front1`, `/foo*` routes to `front2`. Everything is working there perfectly well, however, hosting the solution on Cloud Run would decrease the costs a lot.

So at the moment, I am really struggling to understand how could I fully replicate this behavior in Cloud Run. I've tried following [firebase routing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run), but it requires to host an app on Firebase as well and doesn't route all traffic for route `/api/**` to my `api` service.

I've tried following [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-load-balancing-go-beyond-your-own-project-adfa1c8b001d), but I cannot select my service since I selected Internet Network Ednpoint Group option for backend type, which only can point to a single url. Also, I am not sure if it will support wildcard routing there.

I'd highly appreciate any help here, I am totally out of options at the moment.

Comment: Something for you to consider  - are you sure hosting on cloud run would decrease your costs a lot? If you're running on GAE Flexible, will your code/App work on GAE Standard instead? Standard is usually cheaper than flexible cos your instance can go down to 0 when there's no traffic (like cloud run) but Flexible requires at least 1 instance to be always up

Comment: @NoCommandLine I can't deploy my API to Standard environment since .NET is not supported in Standard environment. Frontend services are on standard environment and their costs satisfy me, but API is billing is concerning.

Comment: I suggest you use the [billing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to try to see if this will save you as much money as you think it might, this is because cloud run is always running while App Engine instances can work depending on usage.

Comment: @HipsterCat thats not true, Cloud Run is scaling to 0 but you can set minimum running instances if you need.